# Android Tutorial: Enter message to display in another activity

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-layout

I am a beginner in Android, and I need some advice/help with the following issue as I'm doing an Android tutorial http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#AddToManifest. I got a little problem here when running the app it displays a BLANK ACTIVITY of myfirstapp (both on emulator and my Samsung Galaxy S2) - it doesn't show up anything on the app - no text field, no button.

**MainActivity.java:**

```
    package com.example.myfirstapp;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE ="com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Get the message from the intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        // Create the text view
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText(message);
        // Set the text view as the activity layout
        setContentView(textView);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    }
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send"
        android:onClick="sendMessage" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_display_message.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".DisplayMessageActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myfirstapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**However when I remove this particular piece of code from my main activity:**

```
// Create the text view
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setTextSize(40);
textView.setText(message);
// Set the text view as the activity layout
setContentView(textView);
```

**It will run an app as normally showing everything although it won't process the text entered. Once you click on the button it will only show up a new activity with Hello World. Any ideas where the problem occurs?**

Comment: A good idea is to separate your code snippets into different sections

Comment: So many downvotes are discouraging for newbies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you are aware that in the tutorial **two** classes are used - `MainActivity` and `DisplayMessageActivity` - it seems you've merged them into one class accidentally.

Comment: That's right, I put it all in one class by mistake. Problem solved! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following code should be in the onCreate method of DisplayMessageActivity.java and not in MainActivity.java

```
 // Get the message from the intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    // Create the text view
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);
    // Set the text view as the activity layout
    setContentView(textView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting anything in the `message` variable. If it is empty then nothing will be set in the `setText(message)` and hence nothing will be displayed.